# jQuery's clone() function messes up original element's property

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clone

I have this seemingly simple problem. I first check a radio button, then clone it. The original radio button becomes unchecked, and the cloned one is correct. Can anyone tell me why the original radio button becomes unchecked?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ClonedDiv" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="RadioDiv">
        <input id="high"   type="radio" name="severity" value="High"/>
        <input id="medium" type="radio" name="severity" value="Medium"/>
        <input id="low"    type="radio" name="severity" value="Low"/>
    </div>
    <script>
            $("#RadioDiv #high").prop("checked", true);
            alert("RadioDiv's High is: " + ($("#RadioDiv #high")[0].checked ? "CHECKED." : "NOT CHECKED!") );
            $("#ClonedDiv").empty();
            $("#RadioDiv>input").clone().appendTo("#ClonedDiv"); // I'm merely cloning RadioDiv's inputs into ClonedDiv...
            alert("RadioDiv's High is: " + ($("#RadioDiv #high")[0].checked ? "CHECKED." : "NOT CHECKED!") );
            alert("ClonedDiv's High is: " + ($("#ClonedDiv #high")[0].checked ? "CHECKED." : "NOT CHECKED!") );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be the normal behavior, it doesn't seem to be related to jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/V5rAW/. I think you could argue whether cloning a radio button should also clone its current state, but SO is not the right place to discuss such things.

Comment: Either change the `name` attribute or remove the `checked` attribute from cloned radio button before appending if you want the original button to stay checked.

Comment: That's what I find funny. The cloned element is correct, but the original isn't --> its state is lost. Is this documented anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: Ah... I think Mathew's answered my question. Apparently, now there are 6 radio buttons, but they all have the same name. How stupid of me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one radio button in a group can be checked. Checking one un-checks all others. A grouping of radio buttons is determined by them all having the same name attribute. Cloning them into the hidden div and then checking one un-checks the other.

Comment: This is an obvious answer that is difficult to see mainly because the behaviour is unique for radios and probably Dunnomuch (as well as myself) had different input types in the cloned box.